# Changing values in nested lists with python

Tags: python, list

Ok, with the same program previously I've now hit a problem I should have anticipated; the grid (of variable width and height) is constructed based on a code to alternate the symbols which creates a list, those lists are then stored in the grid as nested lists. below is a section of code for making the list (called line) the odd numbered width is necessary.

```
1 - + -
2 + - + 
3 - + -

   if gridwidth % 2 != 0: 
        for i in range(gridwidth):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                line.append('-')
            else:
                line.append('+')
```

Edit - sorry I didn't want to spam with code; the lines are put into the list grid below;

```
    grid = []
    for i in range(height):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            grid.append(line)
        else:
            grid.append(linerev)
```

line is then appended to grid by the range(height) and there is another block of code to handle the alternating lines which creates another list (linerev) - my problem is that because of how the grid is created, if I try to change a value in it say turn grid[0,0] into a + or -, it changes it along several rows as grid[1,0], grid[5,0] etc are all referring the the same list - is there any way to avoid this without using global variables, deep copy, or drastically revising how the grid is created? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you aren't showing enough code. We need to see how you added line to grid.

Comment: sorry! hopefully that's better?

Comment: If you want to avoid spamming with code, you should remove irrealvent pieces of code, not parts that directly impinge on the question at hand.

Comment: cool taken on board, I guess I thought that the construction of the lists within the lists was somehow more relevant. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make copies of the lists when you add them:

```
grid = []
for i in range(height):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        grid.append(line[:])
    else:
        board.append(linerev[:])
```

Comment: Cheers, I hadn't even thought of doing that